# I'm getting an error from gcc on my lex code: "#endif without #if"

Tags: lex

This is my first attempt at writing a compiler using flex and bison.  I wrote what look to me like legal lex and yacc code, but when I run it through the compiler I get an error message.  This seems to come from gcc, so it's something wrong with the code generated by flex.

ghlex.l:20:2: error: #endif without #if
 .map return DOTMAP;

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with the .map pattern and/or action?
(In case it's not obvious or I miscoded it, that's supposed to match the token ".map")

Here's my lex/flex source code:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "gh.tab.h"
%}
DIGIT       [0-9]
STARTCHAR   [_a-zA-Z]
WORDCHAR    {DIGIT}|{STARTCHAR}
FILECHAR    {WORDCHAR}|[-.+@#$%()]
FILECHAR1   {FILECHAR}|[/" ]
FILECHAR2   {FILECHAR}|[/' ]
 /* special "start states" for matching
%s DESC FNAME1 FNAME2
%%
{DIGIT}+    yylval.number = atoi(yytext); return INT;
{STARTCHAR}{WORDCHAR}* yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return WORD;
FILECHAR$   yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return FILEPART;
'FILECHAR1+'        yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return QUOTE;
"FILECHAR2+"        yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return QUOTE;
\.map       return DOTMAP;
\.m return DOTM;
\.r return DOTR;
\.c return DOTC;
\.d return DOTD;
\.t return DOTT;
\.o return DOTO;
\.u return DOTU;
\.v return DOTV;
,   return COMMA;
\+  return PLUS;
-   return MINUS;
\/  return SLASH;
;   return SEMI;
\[  return LBRACKET;
\]  return RBRACKET;
\%\$        return PCTDOL;
\%\/        return PCTSLASH;
\%t return PCTT;
\%@ return PCTAT;
\n  /* ignore newlines */
[ \t]       /* ignore whitespace */
\/\/        /* ignore c++-style comments */
<DESC>.*    yylval.string = strdup(yytext); return STRING;
%%
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your unterminated comment on line 12:

```
  /* special "start states" for matching
```

since this line begins with whitespace, it is copied verbatim into the lex.yy.c file, where it screws things up, commenting out several following lines generated by flex, including an `#ifdef` and the `#line` directives that would make the compiler output better line number information.

If you compile with `-Wall` (which you ALWAYS should), you'll get a `warning: "/*" within comment` *before* the error, which at least hints that the problem is related to comments (though this message too has an incorrect line number.)

Comment: THanks, that solved it. Now I can go on to writing code generation.